# Difficult to setup the text header from \section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, context

I am trying to prepare my document step by step but every time I face a **pebcak** that blocks me.

I am trying to display on the header the section mark, useless to say that whatever I try is not working.

Here is my preamble:

```
% language=en

%%% Anything that is not related with layout

% Enable fake text
\usemodule[visual]
\setupsystem[random=10]

% define language

\mainlanguage[en]

%%%

% Setup paper size
\setuppapersize[letter][letter]
\setuplayout[topspace=0.5in,
    backspace=1in,
    header=24pt,
    footer=36pt,
    height=middle,
    width=middle]

% the following comment can show layout
%\showframe

% Numbering Pages
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,
    location={footer,inleft},
    style=bold]
    
%%% Setup Head

\setuphead[chapter][
    style=\bold,
    number=no,
    after=\pagebreak
    ]   
    
\setuphead[section][
        style=\italic,
        number=no,
        ]
        
%%% Setup Sections

% Chapter 

\chapter [
    title={\WORDS{terminals \& connector}}
    ]
    
% Section

\section[
    list={Copper Ring Terminal Lugs},
    marking={Copper Ring Terminal Lugs}
    ]   

% Subject

\define[2]\prodsub{
%   \blank[2*line]
    \startpacked[0.5mm]
        \subject[title=\WORD{#1}]
        {\tfx\bs\WORDS{#2}}
    \stoppacked
}

%%% Header & Footer

% Headers
\setupheader[style=\bold]
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[section]}]

% Footers
\setupfooter[styleleft=\sl,styleright=\bold]
\setupfootertexts[\WORDS{WEBSITE.com}][][][\WORDS{terminals \& connectors}]

% Body font

\setupbodyfont[ivona,8pt]
```

The most interesting thing is the following command work if use for instance `chapter` or `sectionnumber`:

```
%% Both way work but with everything but section

%%% Basic
\setupheadertexts[chapter]

%%%
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[chapter]}]
```

I can't understand why `chapter` works and `section` doesn't, while `sectionnumber` does. This a clear **pebcak**...

Perhaps the issue lies on the body:

```
\starttext

% Cover here

% TOC here

% Verso

% Copper Ring Terminal lugs

\startsection

\prodsub{item 001}{crimp type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 002}{crimp type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 003}{crimp type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 004}{crimp type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 005}{crimp type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 006}{solder type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 007}{solder type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 008}{solder type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 009}{solder type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 010}{solder type copper ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

% Ring Terminals

\prodsub{item 011}{solder type ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 012}{solder type ring terminal lug}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
    \item \fakewords{3}{10}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 013}{0 awg gold plated ring terminals}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 014}{4 awg gold plated ring terminals}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 015}{8 awg gold plated ring terminals}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 016}{10 awg gold plated ring terminals}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
    \item \fakewords{2}{8}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 017}{0 awg gold plated ring terminals}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 018}{0 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
    \item \fakewords{2}{5}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 019}{0 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 020}{0 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 021}{4 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 022}{4 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 023}{6 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 024}{6 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 025}{0 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 026}{0 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 027}{10 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 028}{10 awg ring terminal - bulk pack}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 029}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{item 030}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1210-3/8}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1210-1/4}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1614-10}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1614-5/16}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1614-3/8}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-1614-1/4}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-2218-10}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-rt-2218-1/4}{vinyl insulated ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
    \item \fakewords{2}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mrt-1210-8hs}{marine heat shrink ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mrt-1614-6hs}{marine heat shrink ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mrt-2218-4hs}{marine heat shrink ring terminal}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

% Butt Connectors

\prodsub{mbt-1210-hs}{marine heat shrink butt connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mbt-1614-hs}{marine heat shrink butt connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mbt-2218-hs}{marine heat shrink butt connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mqd-1210-250hs}{marine heat shrink butt disconnect connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mqd-1614-250hs}{marine heat shrink butt disconnect connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{mqd-2218-250hs}{marine heat shrink butt disconnect connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-1210}{vinyl but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-1614}{vinyl but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-2218}{vinyl but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-1210nl}{nylon but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-1614nl}{nylon but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\prodsub{is-bt-2218nl}{nylon but connector}
\startitemize[1]
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
    \item \fakewords{1}{3}
\stopitemize

\stopsection
% ends of the document

\stoptext
```

Hope to resolve it to move to the next **pebcak**, thanks!

Comment: I guess I might found the pebcak... *"A not so short intro..."* states: `startsection [option] [variables] ... \stopsection` **in Mark IV is [...] that is recommended** (Ch. 7.3, page 130, English version). This maybe solves also my second pebcak...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by myself…

I "resolved" two problems I have been facing so far:

1. Couldn't pass the `\section` **"marks"** to the **header text**.
2. Couldn't understand how to use different section markings across the document and pass them to each related **header text**.

The hints was suggested by this passage at page 130 of **"Not So Short Intro…"** :

> All section commands, including any levels created by the user (see section 7.5), allow the following alternative forms of syntax (if, for example, we are using the “section” level):
>
> `\section [Label]{Title}`
>
> `\section [Options]`
>
> `\startsection [Options] [Variables] ... \stopsection`
>
> In the three ways above, arguments between square brackets are optional and can be omitted. We will look at them separately, but **first of all it helps to make it clear that in Mark IV it is the third of these three approaches that is recommended.** *(emphases mine)*

Eventually, I though that I could create customized environments in order to respect the *preferred* method to pass the *section mark* to the *header text*; therefore I used the command `definstartstop`, I spent hours to understand why it wouldn't work, than observing better in the wiki I noticed that the values given in `before:` and `after:` fields were wrapped within curly brackets. From this point the last pebcak was nesting properly the commands within the right brackets order… ‍

Below the snippets that control the sections and headers in the preamble:

**\definestartstop**

```
% Define sections with Roman numbers
% secItac: Copper Ring Terminal Lugs
% secIItac: Ring Terminals
% secIIItac: Butt Connectors

\definestartstop
    [SecItac]
    [before={\startsection
        [bookmark={\Words{copper ring terminal lugs}},marking={\Words{copper ring terminal lugs}}]},
    after={\stopsection}]
    
\definestartstop
    [SecIItac]
    [before={\startsection[bookmark={\Words{ring terminals}},marking={\Words{ring terminals}}]},
    after={\stopsection}]
    
\definestartstop
    [SecIIItac]
    [before={\startsection[bookmark={\Words{butter ring}},marking={\Words{butter ring}}]}
    after={\stopsection}]
```

**headers** — the second command is suggested at page 104, second bullet point.

```
% Headers
\setupheader[style=\bold]
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[section]}]
```

The **body** thus can looks like:

```
\starttext

\startSecItac

The First Section…

\stopSecItac

\startSecIItac

The Second Section…

\stopSecIItac

\startSecIIItac

The Third Section…

\stopSecIIItac
```

tac is the acronom of this imaginary chapter (Terminals & Connectors).

I agreed that for many expert this might look too way simplistic but for me has been pretty challenging, and I look forward to build more complex environments! For instance I had to write twice the same name but I might be used a variable for each environment, this might be a further enhancement…

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I read that you can even use commands that accept metadata, I don't know if this can be done with the *SECTIONS* and the like, but for what I learned so far I found the method below:

```
% Define sections with Roman numbers
% secItac: Copper Ring Terminal Lugs
% secIItac: Ring Terminals
% secIIItac: Butt Connectors

% Section pseudo-variables

\define\SecI{\Words{copper ring terminal lugs}}
\define\SecII{\Words{ring terminals}}
\define\SecIII{\Words{butter connectors}}

\definestartstop
    [SecItac]
    [before={\startsection
        [bookmark={\SecI},marking={\SecI}]},
    after={\stopsection}]
    
\definestartstop
    [SecIItac]
    [before={\startsection
        [bookmark={\SecII},marking={\SecII}]},
    after={\stopsection}]

\definestartstop
    [SecIIItac]
    [before={\startsection
        [bookmark={\SecIII},marking={\SecIII}]},
    after={\stopsection}]

% Headers
\setupheader[style=\bold]
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[section]}]
```

In my case I would the text header centered on the page.